# Java REST threads are in RUNNABLE state forever in wildfly 10.0

Tags: rest, java-8, wildfly, wildfly-10, undertow

in our production server I found a strange behaviore where the **REST POST** threads **sometimes** hangs or stuck and remain in **RUNNABLE** state for ever in method **sun.nio.ch.PollArrayWrapper.poll0(Native Method)**

after some days the wildfly app server become unresponsive and consume high CPU.

here is a print screen form our javamelody monitoring that show some of the hanging threads in a **RUNNABLE** state for more that **50 hours** (and counting).

[image]

To be sure I took some jstack trace files and I found the same threads are still thier and in **RUNNABLE** state.

The **default task-302** thread stack (from thread dump file) as follows ..

```
"default task-302" #1054 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd55c19b800 nid=0x666b runnable [0x00007fd5161a6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.PollArrayWrapper.poll0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PollArrayWrapper.poll(PollArrayWrapper.java:115)
    at sun.nio.ch.PollSelectorImpl.doSelect(PollSelectorImpl.java:87)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x0000000612c0f7e0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$3)
    - locked <0x0000000612c0f7d0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x0000000612c07e10> (a sun.nio.ch.PollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
    at org.xnio.nio.SelectorUtils.await(SelectorUtils.java:46)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.awaitReadable(NioSocketConduit.java:345)
    at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.SslConduit.awaitReadable(SslConduit.java:281)
    at org.xnio.conduits.AbstractSourceConduit.awaitReadable(AbstractSourceConduit.java:66)
    at org.xnio.conduits.AbstractSourceConduit.awaitReadable(AbstractSourceConduit.java:66)
    at io.undertow.conduits.ReadDataStreamSourceConduit.awaitReadable(ReadDataStreamSourceConduit.java:101)
    at io.undertow.conduits.FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.awaitReadable(FixedLengthStreamSourceConduit.java:285)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.awaitReadable(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:151)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSourceChannel.awaitReadable(DetachableStreamSourceChannel.java:77)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$ReadDispatchChannel.awaitReadable(HttpServerExchange.java:2092)
    at org.xnio.channels.Channels.readBlocking(Channels.java:295)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.readIntoBuffer(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:170)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.read(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:146)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ProviderHelper.readString(ProviderHelper.java:66)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StringTextStar.readFrom(StringTextStar.java:40)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StringTextStar.readFrom(StringTextStar.java:22)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:61)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:60)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:53)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalVerificationInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(DigitalVerificationInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:151)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:91)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:202)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:201)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.unilever.merchandizer.views.filters.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:176)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.unilever.merchandizer.views.filters.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:33)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at com.unilever.merchandizer.views.filters.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:40)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.MetricsHandler.handleRequest(MetricsHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.MetricsChainHandler.handleRequest(MetricsChainHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea or hint about the issue root cause ?
Is it wildfly or undertow issue ?
is it JDK 8 bug ? or something in the application code that I have to check

Environment:

- JDK: jdk1.8.0_112
- OS: centOS 7
- Wildfly 10.0 (with undertow version 1.3.15 final)
- Java EE 7 app

Comment: The stack would indicate to me that your server waits on some resource to become readable again (from all `awaitReadable` methods in it). Try first seeing if you have resource leak in your application. For example, if you don't close a `Connection` or `InputStream/OutputStream` or `Reader/Writer`.

Comment: unfortunately I did not find any leak in my simple REST POST method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of this issue was due to an android activity that uses retrofit library to interact with our web service.  But in certain cases it let the connection with the server open and hence the server thread is in runnable state.

to fix this from the server side, we added timeout settings in the HTTP and HTTPS module in wildfly. this action solved the case.